# How to sort an RDD and limit in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have RDD of Foo class : `class Foo( name : String, createDate : Date )`.
I want an other RDD with 10 percent older `Foo`.
My first idea was to sort by `createDate` and limit by 0.1*count, but there is no limit function.

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming `Foo` is a case class like this:

```
import java.sql.Date
case class Foo(name: String, createDate: java.sql.Date)
```

1. Using plain RDDs:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
   import scala.math.Ordering

   val rdd: RDD[Foo] = sc
     .parallelize(Seq(
       ("a", "2015-01-03"), ("b", "2014-11-04"), ("a", "2016-08-10"),
       ("a", "2013-11-11"), ("a", "2015-06-19"), ("a", "2009-11-23")))
     .toDF("name", "createDate")
     .withColumn("createDate", $"createDate".cast("date"))
     .as[Foo].rdd

   rdd.cache()
   val  n = scala.math.ceil(0.1 * rdd.count).toInt
   ```

   - data fits into driver memory:

     - and fraction you want is relatively small

       ```
       rdd.takeOrdered(n)(Ordering.by[Foo, Long](_.createDate.getTime))
       // Array[Foo] = Array(Foo(a,2009-11-23))
       ```
     - fraction you want is relatively large:

       ```
       rdd.sortBy(_.createDate.getTime).take(n)
       ```
   - otherwise

     ```
     rdd
       .sortBy(_.createDate.getTime)
       .zipWithIndex
       .filter{case (_, idx) => idx < n}
       .keys
     ```
2. Using DataFrame (note - this is actually not optimal performance wise due to limit behavior).

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

   val topN = rdd.toDF.orderBy($"createDate").limit(n)
   topN.show

   // +----+----------+
   // |name|createDate|
   // +----+----------+
   // |   a|2009-11-23|
   // +----+----------+


   // Optionally recreate RDD[Foo]
   topN.map{case Row(name: String, date: Date) => Foo(name, date)}
   ```

Comment: Hi zero323 can you tell really quick why DataFrame's performance is suboptimal on limit operation? what is difference compare to top on RDD in implementation wise? @zero333

Comment: @XinweiLiu I already provided an answer to your question. I hope it explains what is going on.

Comment: Great answer @zero323. But I still have the same question xinwei Liu has. Why df.limit() is slow?

Comment: @zero323 Please provide more insight into why df.limit(n) is slow. Thank you.

Comment: I think `.zipWithIndex` is not safe to use in this context. Maybe `zipWithUniqueId` is safer ? Oh and why `limit` is slow ?

Comment: for the limit question: http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/What-happens-in-Dataset-limit-followed-by-rdd-td18526.html

Comment: If the rdd is essentially limitless, sorting it, or zipping with index seems like a bad idea. Is there no way to limit to 10^6 items, say, and not even creating the remaining?

Comment: If the number you want to limit is large, do a cache between sort and limit will significantly boost the performance. Don't use a limit directly followed with sort, especially when n is large, that will affect how Spark allocates resources.